# Filter result from a single name in a SET with multiple entries

Tags: php, mysql, list, set, where-clause

I have a column of SET type made up of creators of comic books.

In PHP, I do a query to get all the comics with a single creator.

If I do a query using WHERE `creator = "John Byrne"`, I can see every entry where `John Byrne` is the only and single item, but as soon as I have more than one item in my SET, nothing appears...

Here's an example of the query:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM comic_list AS A LEFT JOIN title_list AS B ON A.title = B.title_ID WHERE A.creators='John Byrne'";`

Comment: Use `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Comment: @Barmar I have this query: 
```$sql = "SELECT * FROM comic_list AS A LEFT JOIN title_list AS B ON A.title = B.title_ID WHERE FIND_IN_SET ('Chip Zdarsky')";```

I get this error: ``` Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool ```

Comment: You didn't say what column to search in your call to `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Comment: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Chip Zdarsky', A.creators)`

Comment: @Barmar Fantastic, it worked!  Thanks again for your time and patience, it's greatly appreciated.